# Installing Kasa smart dimmer 3 way with only 4 wires?

Tags: dimmer-switch, multiway-switch, smart-switch

I have some lights controllable by two toggle switches on opposite sides of the room. Im located in the US in an older house, Im trying to install a Kasa Smart Dimmable 3-way Switch (KS230). However when I open both of the old toggle switches I only see 4 wires (1xBlack, 1xWhite, 1xRed, 1xCopper) (red opposite white, black opposite copper).

The Kasa seems to require 5 wires for the main (2xTravelers, 1xLine, 1xNeutral, 1xGround) but four for the satellite (2xTraveler, 1xload, 1xground). Why am I missing cables? How should it be wired up? Am I wrong for calling this a 3-way switch?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Both switches have the same layout of wires, just one is upside down.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pictures of the switch wires and how they are connected will help a lot.  Possible you just have two single switches and a three way will not work.

Comment: If it's two single switches can smart switches be installed? I can't post pictures as they are too big, but the red is opposite the white and the black is opposite the copper.

Comment: You need both hot and neutral in one of the boxes. Based on your description, you likely (but not guaranteed...) have one cable with either hot or switched hot + 2 travelers + ground. Which means the other switch *may* have what you need. Need pictures of both boxes/switches.

Comment: Having trouble posing pictures, but both switches show the same layout (red opposite white, black opposite copper)

Comment: I made a solution, provided you can email the pictures - see https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1582/image-shrinking-upload for details.

Comment: Use the mountains and sun icon to upload pics and someone will have an answer for you.

Comment: @HoneyDo OP is hitting the image size limit problem.

Comment: Attached at photo,  both switches are the same, except one is upside down.

Comment: Virtually impossible! If they have the same configuration - black/red/white/bare in a single cable - then nothing would ever work, unless there was some wacky splicing somewhere. Far more likely: **one** of these switches has one of the wires going to a *different* cable. Look for it. And then upload pictures showing which wires are going to which cables.

Comment: Added more photos, they are the same just upside down.

Comment: Trace the wires from each switch to the back of the box. Unless you are in conduit land (but then you would probably not have all those bare grounds), the wires will go into *groups* together in the back of the box. Each group has 2 or 3 insulated wires plus bare - the combinations will be black/white/bare or black/white/red/bare. At least one of the switches should have one of the wires going to a *different* cable from the other wires that are attached to that switch.

Comment: Looking at one of them it has a cable that has red, white, black and copper all coming from the same cable. All the wires except the copper goes directly into the switch. The copper seems to be spliced with the copper of the other incoming cable. Photo added

Comment: Which is 100% normal for *one* of a pair of 3-way. (But not guaranteed, there are configurations where neither switch is set up this way.) What about the other one?

Comment: Added another photo. There are 5 bundled cables coming into this box, 4 in the top and one in the bottom. The red and white seem to go into the one in the top right. The black goes to a different cable entirely. And the copper seems to be all bundled together from all the cables.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere!

Comment: Next key questions: In box 1 (the box with the 5 cables is *box 1*), does the black wire go straight off to a cable? Or does it go into the big bundle of black wires? If it goes straight off to a cable, does the white wire in the same cable go to a big bundle of white wires or someplace else?

Comment: Yes, the black wire coming to my switch goes directly into a cable and out of the box. The white wire from that cable seems to be bundled with others.

Comment: Last question (I think): Look at the red and white attached to the box 1 switch. They go to a cable. There is a black in that same cable. Where does that black wire go?

Comment: Appreciate the help by the way. The black wire that spawns from the cable supplying red and white to my switch goes into a screw nut with many other black cables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing things a bit. Based on last question comment, the black going to the switch in box 1 is *switched hot* and the black going to the /3 cable is *hot*. With dumb switches, that's one of a number of possible, equally functional, configurations. But that won't work here - hot and switched hot need to be swapped.

Terminology: /2 = black/white/bare cable. /3 = black/white/red/bare cable. The individual colored things are called wires. The groups are cables. All grounds together and ignored for general purposes - they are important but since they all go together everywhere, they don't affect how things are connected.

Based on the pictures and description, what I believe to be the likely scenario is:

##### Box 1:

- Remove the black wire from the switch. This wire is the switched hot. Put a piece of red tape on it.
- Remove the black wire that is part of the /3 cable from the bunch of black wires. Put a piece of red tape on it.
- Use a wire nut to connect the two "red" wires together. That takes care of *switched hot* - it now goes to switch 2.
- Use a short piece of 12 AWG (14 AWG is OK if this is a 15A circuit) black wire to connect from the now-empty common screw on switch 1 to the bunch of black wires. *That takes care of *hot* - it now goes to switch 1.

That now leaves us with:

- /3 = travelers (red and white) + switched hot (black)
- Black on switch goes bundle of hots (incoming power distributed to multiple switches/locations) - "common" screw
- Red and white on switch go to the /3 - the other 2 screws
- Black from /3 goes to light fixture /2 cable
- White from light fixture /2 cable goes to white neutral bundle
- Use a short piece of 12 AWG (14 AWG is OK if this is a 15A circuit) white wire to connect from the neutral bundle to the switch, if the switch (as many smart switches do) requires neutral

In the case of adding a new wire to the black hot bundle or the white neutral bundle, you may need a new wire nut.

##### Box 2:

- /3 = travelers (red and white) + switched hot (black)
- Black goes to common screw
- Red and white go to the other 2 screws

In box 1 you have hot, switched hot, neutral, travelers - everything you could need for any kind of switch.

In box 2 all you have is travelers and switched hot. You can't put a smart switch here unless it repurposes one of the travelers as an always hot *and* it doesn't require neutral.

If you want to improve things a little for future reference, mark the wires as follows:

##### Box 1:

- Red and white on switch - mark both with *yellow* tape
- Black from /3 goes to light fixture /2 cable - mark both with *red* tape

##### Box 2:

- Red and white go to the other 2 screws - mark both with *yellow* tape

That way, looking at tape, and when no tape looking at the natural wire color:

- Black = hot
- White = neutral
- Yellow = traveler
- Red = switched hot

Comment: Hey, really appreciate your help with all this. The Kasa I'm trying to install has a main swich (which I think would go in box 1) requiring (2x travelers, 1xline, 1xground 1xneutral). However the satellite kasa only requires (2x travelers 1xground 1x load). Wouldn't that work in box2? The satellite doesn't require a common like the main switch.

Comment: Correct. Satellite in box 2

Comment: Okay still a bit confused on the common wire and line in box1 for the new switch. Red and white wires go to travelers on new switch. Black from /3 (which is currently going to a wire nut) is....? And the black wire from /2 is....? Sorry for being dense.

Comment: The wire nut of lots of blacks is *hot*. So the black from /3 going to that is *hot*. But that wire needs to be *switched hot*. Similarly, the black from switch 1 is going to the light fixture /2 cable, so that's *switched hot*. And switch 1 needs *hot*.

Comment: In bullet point 4 of Box1 you say to use a black wire to connect to common of new switch 1. Is that the line or neutral socket on the new switch? Apologies if I've caused the confusion between common and neutral, the new switch calls it "neutral" and "line".

Comment: That is *line* in this context. I don't really like the "line" term as much (won't explain here as it would only add to the confusion). **neutral only ever gets white wires** (except sometimes gray, but that's unusual). *common* in this context refers to the connection on a dumb 3-way switch which is not a switched position - i.e., power goes in common and out through one or the other (switched) travelers, or comes in on one or the other (switched) travelers and out on common. That is *not* to be confused with "common" as a rough synonym for "neutral" - which is a confusion that sort of comes

Comment: about from the DC and small electronics world. Suffice it to say that if someone who knows what they're doing (I sometimes do...) says to connect a black or red or yellow or blue wire it will *not* be to neutral. So since I'm talking about connecting a black wire and your choices are "line" or "neutral", it can't be neutral so it must be line.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Got it wired up and all working! Super awesome! Now one day I've gotta do the 3-way in the staircase (the other toggle in box 2 and a single toggle at the top of the stairs) but thats a project for a different day. Again thanks for the help!!!